# Send Labels forward and back in Swift... do I have to?

Tags: swift, uilabel, interface-builder

I would like a UILabel to continually update behind interface elements on the same screen. I can see that my label starts below the other elements by using the Debug View Hierarchy tool in Swift's Xcode tool. As soon as I update the text in the label, it jumps to the top and writes over my other labels and interface elements.

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCPcV.png)
[3D Debugger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I7Kh.png)

First question... I can't find the tool for setting front to back layers in Interface Builder... if someone can point that out to me that'd be great, Google has not been my friend.

Since it's going to end up on top when I update the label, I figure I can send the label to the back whenever I refresh it... In my ViewController.swift file, in the function where I update the label's text, I've tried: (my label's outlet hook is called "consoleMe"

> ```
> super.sendSubview(toBack:consoleMe)
> ```

Nope... that's backwards maybe? So I tried:

> ```
> consoleMe.sendSubview(toBack: super)
> ```

...as well as "self" instead of super. It doesn't like super at all. It complains that self is ViewController and not a UIView.

Finally, I'm wondering if I have to do this at all-- surely there's a way to specify that a UILabel should remain below other stuff?

Am I correct that updating a UILabel automatically brings it to the front (or is something else going on?) I tried to make the other labels and items "opaque" but of course that had no effect as they end up below my console label.

Thanks!
-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendSubview(toBack:)` is a method of `UIView` and all `UIViewController` objects contain a `view` built in.

From the [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller)  documentation:

> **View Management**
>
> Each view controller manages a view hierarchy, the root view of which is stored in the `view` property of this class.

Therefore call `sendSubview(toBack:)` on the `view` property instead:

```
view.sendSubview(toBack: consoleMe)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. From what you wrote, I understand that sendSubview is a function call that is available to UIView. My first guess was closer (ViewController does the work, NOT the UILabel.) Thank you for that! What I do not understand is "all UIViewController objects contain a view built in". I get that my program is creating an instance of the ViewController class, where we are doing everything...is the word "view" referring to a property? Or an instance of another class? I would also love to know if there are ways to pin a control or view's layer in relation to other objects.

Comment: @Beagley Yes `view` is a property of `UIViewController` which you are subclassing when you create your own so you have access to `view`. I added more details to my answer.

Comment: @Beagley Regarding pinning views in relation to other views, look up AutoLayout